# How to create an array of promise objects in Java

Tags: javascript, java, android

In JavaScript we have

```
Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
  //...
});
```

> Promise.all takes an array of promises and creates a promise that fulfills when all of them successfully complete.

This allows me to do something like search the database for multiple different songs (asynchronously) and return the entire batch when the searching is done. How would I do something like [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing) in Java. Specifically, in my android app.